# Unix - Cut from a string

Tags: string, unix, cut

I have log files that are being labelled by the date.  I would like to extract only the day from the log.  So my logs are

```
server01.log-2017-05-08.gz
server00152.log-2017-05-08.gz
```

How do I extract only **08** from the file.  I tried

```
echo "www1-ssl-access.log-2017-05-07.gz" | rev | cut -d"-" -f1  | rev
```

but it extract 08.gz which I do not want.  I just need **08** from the file.  How would I go about doing this?  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You could use AWK like this:

```
echo "www1-ssl-access.log-2017-05-07.gz" | awk -F'[-.]' '{ print $(NF - 1) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sed to the end to remove the .gz

```
echo "www1-ssl-access.log-2017-05-07.gz" | rev | cut -d"-" -f1  | rev | sed -e 's/.gz//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash only:

```
$ i="www1-ssl-access.log-2017-05-07.gz"  # set to var i
$ j=${i##*-}                             # remove from last - to beginning
$ echo ${j%%.*}                          # remove from first . to end and echo
07
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` and remember a part between `\(` ans `\)`:

```
echo "www1-ssl-access.log-2017-05-07.gz" | sed 's/.*-\([^.]*\)\.gz/\1/'
```

You can change the `sed` command according to the variations of your input.
When the file is not compressed, you may still want to get the number.

```
printf "%s\n" "www1-ssl-access.log-2017-05-07" "www1-ssl-access.log-2017-05-07.gz" | 
   sed 's/.*-\([^.]*\).*/\1/'
```